# Can't catch Celery Operational Error in Django

Tags: django, celery

I have the following code:

```
def save()
   super().save(*args, **kwargs)
   try:
       transaction.on_commit(lambda: c_task.delay(a, b, self.pk))
   except Exception as e:
       print(e)

@app.task(bind=True, name='c_task', max_retries=4, soft_time_limit_exception=300)
def c_task(self, a, b, i):

    from .models import ModelA

    try:
        json_data = entity(a,b,i, const)
        .....
    except Exception as e:

        raise self.retry(exc=e, countdown=exponential_backoff(self))
```

If Redis server fails I receive and OperationalError. I try to catch it using the Celery OperationalError or generic exception as before.

The line is still executing and throw the error. If Redis fails I don't want everything to fail, because my code has a 'workaround', but I can't catch the error.

Traceback:

```
 transaction.on_commit(lambda: c_task.delay(a, b, self.pk))

\lib\site-packages\celery\app\task.py in delay

            return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)

lib\site-packages\celery\app\task.py in apply_async

                **options

\lib\site-packages\celery\app\base.py in send_task

                    amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)

\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__

                    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)

\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py in _reraise_as_library_errors

                        sys.exc_info()[2])

\lib\site-packages\vine\five.py in reraise

                raise value.with_traceback(tb)

\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py in _reraise_as_library_errors

                yield
\lib\site-packages\celery\app\base.py in send_task

                    self.backend.on_task_call(P, task_id)
\lib\site-packages\celery\backends\redis.py in on_task_call

                self.result_consumer.consume_from(task_id)

\lib\site-packages\celery\backends\redis.py in consume_from

                return self.start(task_id)

 \lib\site-packages\celery\backends\redis.py in start

            self._consume_from(initial_task_id)

\lib\site-packages\celery\backends\redis.py in _consume_from

                self._pubsub.subscribe(key)
\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py in subscribe

            ret_val = self.execute_command('SUBSCRIBE', *iterkeys(new_channels))

 \lib\site-packages\redis\client.py in execute_command

            self._execute(connection, connection.send_command, *args)

\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py in _execute

                connection.connect()

d\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py in connect

                raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: @WillKeeling add it; I know that Redis fails, but I want to catch the error, and do something else; the try except doesn't 'catch' the exceptions. I suppose because of lambda, but is needed for Django method to work

Comment: This is coming as a unhandled exception so you want to say? Even when you have a exception handler in `save`

Comment: yes, it give me an Operational Error, even if I have a try/except block;which is very bad of usability

Comment: Can you move the `c_task.delay(a, b, self.pk)` to a new method and then pass that method to `transaction.on_commit`, in this new method add the error handling and see if it helps

Comment: [`transaction.on_commit()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit) doesn't run the function - it registers the function to run when the transaction ends. Therefore wrapping it in `try..except` isn't going to work.

Comment: @Alasdair, i hope your comment was pointed to OP as I am asking to handle this inside `lambda` and not outside like you said?

Comment: @TarunLalwani No, my comment wasn't directed at you.

Comment: @Alasdair, would like to disagree on that. If you look at the stack trace, it starts with `\lib\site-packages\celery\app\task.py in delay` and ends with `d\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py in connect`. Which indicates the issue is when the task has to be pushed to redis and not when the task is running. And that failure would anyways be shown on the worker side and not on the server side

Comment: @TarunLalwani my mistake, I've removed that part of the comment

Comment: @TarunLalwani solution works; if I move the try except to another function(as intermediary) that has the only purpose to call the task the error is catch; thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change below

```
transaction.on_commit(lambda: c_task.delay(a, b, self.pk))
```

to

```
def run_task(a, b, pk):
   try:
      c_task.delay(a, b, pk)
   except Exception as ex:
      print(ex)
transaction.on_commit(lambda: run_task(a, b, self.pk))
```

This will make sure the connection exception is handled